# Range for warning message isn't working

Tags: iphone, c, xcode, range

I'm trying to get a range of 30 to 37, if it's between these numbers, I want no alert to show. If it's below or above I would like to display an alert. Here's my code that's not giving the alert the way I want.

```
if (slope <= 30 && slope >= 37) {
MyMessage;
}
```

Where am I going wrong here? Tried changing the `<>` every way I can think of, and not getting the desired outcome. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use logical or instead of logical and:

```
if (slope <= 30 || slope >= 37) {
    MyMessage;
}
```

You were asking if slope is <= 30 and >= 37. It can't be both. You want to ask if slope is <= 30 or >= 37, either one.